# How do I replace a specific range of positions in a line with a string?

Tags: bash, sed

I have a file ($pdbin) with lines following a specific format. I am trying to replace characters 57-60 with a string variable $o using sed, only on lines that match two specific patterns (contain HETATM and NO).

Here is an example line I want to modify, with the characters I want to change highlighted:

```
HETATM 1111  N   NO  A 204       4.938  19.295  -6.772  1.00 37.21           N
                                                        ^^^^
```

Here is the sed command I have, which replaces the correct characters (and saves to new file `$xyzin`), but by searching for `1.00`, not using the position on the line:

```
sed "/HETATM/{/NO/{s/1.00/$o/g}}" $pdbin > $xyzin
```

The variable `$o` I want to substitute in is `0.12`.

How do I modify this command to operate on positions `57-60`, so that it works if string I want to replace doesn't match `1.00`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can capture first 56 characters in a capture group and put it back in replacement using a back-reference:

```bash
sed -E "/HETATM/{/NO/{s/(^.{56}).{4}/\1$o/;};}" "$pdbin" > "$xyzin"

cat "$xyzin"
HETATM 1111  N   NO  A 204       4.938  19.295  -6.772  0.12 37.21           N
```

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly. Am I right in understanding it as;
Storing the first 56 characters using "(^.{56})";
Changing the next 4 characters with ".{$}";
Replacing the first 56 with"\1";
Adding the variable "$o";
And the rest of the line gets left as is?

Comment: Yes, that is absolutely right

Answer (score 1):

Using any awk in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ awk -v o="$o" '/HETATM/ && /NO/{$0=substr($0,1,56) o substr($0,61)} 1' file
HETATM 1111  N   NO  A 204       4.938  19.295  -6.772  0.12 37.21           N
```

or more robustly by using full literal string comparisons on specific fields rather than partial regexp comparisons on the whole line:

```
$ awk -v o="$o" '($1=="HETATM") && ($4=="NO"){$0=substr($0,1,56) o substr($0,61)} 1' file
HETATM 1111  N   NO  A 204       4.938  19.295  -6.772  0.12 37.21           N
```